# Which of these are constructible numbers?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Which of these are constructible numbers?

$$-\frac35\quad,\quad27^\frac16+2i\quad,\quad2^\frac13\quad,\quad e^{\frac{\pi i}{10}}$$

Please tell me how you came to the answer too.
Thanks!

Comment: What's the defintion of a constructible number?

Comment: See [Constructible number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number)

Comment: @Eric, are there *at least some* numbers in that list that you can identify as belonging to some extension of the rationals of order a power of two? And some that you are positive are **not** ?

Comment: @Timbuc I did some research and I think I know the answer.
-3/5 is constructible since it is rational number.
27^1/6 is constructible since it is simply 3^1/2
2^1/3 is not constructible
e^(pi i /10) is not constructible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so you already know what numbers are constructible and what not. Now, why? Be sure to complete the following arguments, and remember: a number is constructible iff it belongs to a tower of field extension each of which is of degree two, i.e. $\;z\in\Bbb C\;$ is constructible iff $\;z\in K\;,\;\;K\;$ a subfield of $\;\Bbb C\;$ , and such that

$$\Bbb Q=K_0\subset K_1\subset K_2\subset\ldots\subset K_n =K\;,\;\text{and}\;\;[K_i:K_{i-1}]=2\;\;\;\forall\; i=1,2,...,n\;,\;\;or\;\; K=\Bbb Q$$

So:

$$\begin{align*}&-\frac35\in\Bbb Q\implies\color{red}{-\frac35\;\;\text{constructible}}\\{}\\
&\begin{cases}27^{1/6}=\sqrt3\in\Bbb Q{\sqrt3}\;\;\text{and}\;\;[Q(\sqrt3:\Bbb Q]=2\\{}\\2i\in\Bbb Q(i)\;\;\text{and}\;\;[\Bbb Q(i):\Bbb Q]=2\end{cases}\implies\color{red}{\sqrt[6]{27}+2i\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt3,i)\;\;\text{constructible}}\\{}\\
&e^{\pi i/10}=e^{2\pi i/20}\;\;\text{and}\;\;\varphi(20)=8=2^3\implies\;\color{red}{e^{\pi i/10}\;\;\text{constructible, or follows also from:}}\\{}\\&\text{the fact that the minimal polynomial over the rationals of}\;\;e^{\pi i/10}\;\;\text{is}\;\;x^8-x^6+x^4-x^2+1\end{align*}$$

This last result follows from factoring $\;x^{10}+1=\left(x^2\right)^5+1\;$ .

Finally

$$\sqrt[3]2\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2:\Bbb Q]=3\implies \color{green}{\sqrt[3]2\;\;\text{isn't constructible}}$$

Comment: Thanks Timbuc,
I am having hard time understanding.
What is [Ki : Ki-1] ? and why is it = 2 for sqrt(3) and 3 for 2^1/3 ?
Also, how is p(20)=8 ?

Comment: @EricKim, you know some fields, fields extensions and Galois Theory? that $\;\varphi\;$ is Euler's totient Function.